# What does さあ (saa) mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I have seen this term used a lot in many different ways.

「さあ、忘れましょうその未来が」 *saa, wasuremashou sono mirai ga* — in this sense, I assume it means "come".
But I have also seen it used as
「でもさあ」 *demo saa* — which I would assume means "well you know" or some other expression.

Would like to get some more clarification on this word.
I know it is informal to use. But the actual meaning and when it is appropriate to use it would help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

We are actually talking about two different words here.

When used in phrases such as 「さあ、[忘]{わす}れましょう」 and「さあ、[行]{い}きましょう」, 「さあ」  is an exclamation/interjection expressing the speaker's intention to invite or press the other person to perform an action.  It has a meaning close to that of "okay", "now" and "c'mon".

When 「さあ」 is used in phrases such as 「でもさあ」,「あのさあ」 and 「それでさあ」, it is just a filler meaning nothing.  Grammatically, it is a particle.  It is used like "um", "like", "ah", etc. in English.  Strictly speaking, the dictionary word is just 「さ」 and 「さあ」 is only its variant pronunciation.

For a filler, each native speaker has his "usual" one that he uses repeatedly, which means that not everyone uses 「さ」 or 「さあ」 actively.  Other choices include 「ね」,
「ねえ」, 「よ」, 「よう」, etc.

Comment: is まあ　also a filler word?

Comment: It's my impression that it is also used as a negative response when someone doesn't want to explicitly state one, but wants to sort of brush you off anyway. For example, asking for something from a counter worker at city hall that they can't provide (or for which it would be bothersome for them to provide). "Would it be possible to mail me another copy of this record?" "さあ。。。"

Comment: There's also the さあ in response to a question, which basically means 'I have no idea'.

Comment: @Sjiveru Yep, I've seen that quite a bit.  Sometimes it seems as though it might be viewed as 'Well, I might have an idea, but I'm not going to say.'  Maybe that's just me.

Comment: Just adding my 2 cents here but I easily always translate the stand alone: さあ to "who knows" and it fits quite well.

Comment: さ(あ) always struck me a bit like English "so", analogous as a filler word and also in that it conveys a sense of recognition for the way things are.  Meanwhile, まあ has struck me more like "well," when said with a falling or doubtful tone, like "well, no...", injecting a negative sense.  「あれは好きですか。」「まあね。」　→ "Do you like that?"  "Well, kinda."

Comment: so, even though i can't understand it, i am correct to adopt this as a pet peeve?

Answer (score 4):

filler. doesn't mean anything.

If you want to learn when it is appropriate to use it, you just have to copy natives, and learn all the places where it tends to be used.