# the meaning of たまに and んだ

Tags: translation, no-da

たまに would mean occasionally/once in a while right?

how can we translate んだ in this context? or is it just an expression? 
if the translation is wrong, do tell me.

> Text: たまにはなプレゼントをもらっていいと思うんだ。
>   Translation: I think it is okay to receive present once in a while

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: まおらうで doesn't make any sense.  Maybe  もらおうで or もらうで?

Comment: oppsies ! that's a typo. it was supposed to be もらうで ! thank you for correcting me :)

Comment: Can you add a little bit more context?

Comment: I am sorry I dont think I can.

Comment: You also have an extra な in there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes たまに means "occasionally."

んだ at the end of the sentence is not related to たまに. This んだ is the colloquialism for のだ, which is often called *explanatory no(da)*. In your sentence, んだ is not necessary but used for mild emphasis. Most of the time you don't have to translate this のだ explicitly.

- [Explanatory のだ （んだ）](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/)
- [What is the meaning of ～んです?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398)
- [How is the "のです" working here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3349)

By the way, the な after たまには is one of the masculine [filler particles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14924/5010) which do nothing semantically.

Answer (score 1):

> > Text: たまにはなプレゼントをもらっていいと思うんだ。
> >
> > Translation: I think it is okay to receive present once in a while

Yes. This translation is correct. You can also say it without "んだ".

> たまにはプレゼントもらっていいと思う。

You use the first form when you talk to someone.