# What is the meaning of よう in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

ギアをチューンナップしようにも肝心の“G”がなけりゃ**よう**せっかくの俺のギアも弱いまま。

My translation - "I can't even tune up Gear without essential 'G', 
so my precious Gear has to stay wimpy for now."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This よう is [a filler meaning nothing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14924/5010). It's used in the same way as さあ, なあ, のう, etc. If I'm not mistaken, this one is used mainly in Kanto district. Among similar fillers, this one sounds masculine and a bit rough.

**EDIT:** You may have seen a sentence-end よ or よぅ, which is a mild and gentle particle safely used by girls and children. But as a mid-sentence filler, よ sounds fairly differently.