# why the まったく in the sentence implies negative, instead of positive

Tags: grammar

> 「道歩いてんのに人影がまったくね..」

In the manga, the quoted sentence above is shown with an image of deserted road, and I guess the meaning should be something like this:

> 「*I'm walking down the road, but **not a single person in sight**..* 」

But without the picture, I would have mistaken it as:

> 「*I'm walking down the road, but **so many people in sight**..* 」

Please help me understand the grammar of the sentence, because to me it seems like a positive sentence.

Answer (score 13):

This is because まったく is a [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010) that implies (い)ない even without saying it explicitly. The Japanese language has many such phrases.

> Unlike English, Japanese is verb-final, and negation usually comes toward the end of a sentence. Many Japanese NPIs appear early, and they're often signals that a negative predicate is coming up:
>
> In many cases, this signal is strong enough that you can leave out the actual part of the predicate containing the negation (as long as it can be inferred from context):
>
> > ​8a. ちっとも変わらない。
> > ​8b. ちっとも。

So you can say something like this:

> 「寿司は好き？」「まったく。」
> "Do you like sushi?" "Not at all".

This ね after まったく is just a [filler meaning nothing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14924/5010) in particular.

Comment: I think it would be more be more accurate to say that まったく *can* be (*often* is) a negative polarity item, given that it can also be used to express emphatic agreement (as in [「『腹が立つといったら、殴りたい気分だよ』『全くだね』（肯定）」](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%85%A8%E3%81%8F/)).

Answer (score -2):

The ね in this sentence context is the short form of ない,　and 全く means "at all, completely", so 全くね　means "completely nothing" or "not a single thing there".