# Meaning of 全くです in this sentence

Tags: meaning, translation

I saw the sentence

> 前はピザを食べていましたけど、今は全くですね

translated as

"I used to eat pizza, but now I don't eat it at all."

On this case, shouldn't 全く be written as 全くない to express the negativity of "**don't** eat it at all"?

Comment: See this answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/84291/30454

Comment: Amazing, thanks @EddieKal!